# How to detect incoming calls using gammu sms?

Tags: php, sms, gateway, gammu

I'm using Gammu for SMS Gateway

I use php to implement.

I use wavecomm modem.

Gammu is really useful for everything about SMS.

but I want to detect incoming calls.

how to detect incoming call to the modem?

so, if someone calls to the number in the modem, I want to be notified, or I want to send SMS to the caller, like "sorry this number can't receive any calls"

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Recent Gammu SMSD versions can [automatically hangup incoming calls](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/config.html#option-HangupCalls), but there is no finer grained control right now.

Comment: but how to detect incoming call?
so I could send them an sms

Comment: There is no support for that right now, all what Gammu SMSD can do is to hangup.